# How to insert or update a long select statement into a coulmn?

Tags: sql, insert

So i have this is what i want to do

My tables name is GameInvLoc with 3 columns ID, GameLoc, GameInv

```
ID   GameLoc    GameInv
1    Bre        Null
```

I want to do this

```
Update GameInvLoc
   set GameInv = 'select 'ROlID,Whse,Company,LocationNo' union all select concat(id,',',Whse,',',Company,',',LocationNo) from CINT..vwGameReport' 
 where id = 1
```

But i am having problems with the quotation and where they go i get syntax error.

Anybody know the right way to do this?

Comment: you cannot update one column with multiple column of select, use only one column in select statement and also provide name of table before union all clause, better if you can elaborate the issue then I can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use single quote twice to represent a one single quote in string literal.

Something like this:

```
Update GameInvLoc
   set GameInv = 'select ''ROlID,Whse,Company,LocationNo'' union all select concat(id,'','',Whse,'','',Company,'','',LocationNo) from CINT..vwGameReport' 
 where id = 1
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Only tip i have if you have a long one would be better to use text replace tool and replace all single Quotes (') with two single quotes ('') and then put one single quote at the beginning and one at the end of the statement you are trying to update there .